# Don't reduce algebraic fractions in Maple

Tags: function, partial, maple

I would like to do some computations with partially defined functions like `(x-3)^3 / (x-3)`. Maple automatically reduces algebraic fractions with no regard to points like `x = 3`. Unevaulation doesn't help much, because it's stripped before functions (i.e. `solve`) could ever make use of that points.

How should I work with such functions?

Answer (score 0):

For your given example you could try working instead with the expanded forms of numerator (and also of denominator, for some other examples).

Ie,

```
nd := (n,d) -> expand(n)/expand(d):

expr := nd( (x-2)^3, x-2 );

                   3      2           
                  x  - 6 x  + 12 x - 8
                  --------------------
                         x - 2
```

Comment: `(x-3)/(x-3)` is partially defined as well.

Comment: That's why I wrote, "For your given example..."